# How can I copy every dependency (including plugins) to a directory?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I try to copy every dependency to a directory and later I want to be able to replace the local repository with the directory and the project should be able to work in offline mode. That way I can ensure that every dependency is present so later on I can filter through my directory and get all dependencies in the form groupId:artifactId:version:packaging:classifier.

If I use mvn dependency:copy-dependencies I can copy some dependencies in the repository layout but it doesn't copy everything. Even if I use mvn dependency:go-offline first they won't get copied over.

For example if I make mvn install and mvn dependency:go-offline with an empty local repositories I have about 2500 files in my local repository. If I use mvn depndency:copy-dependencies my new directory only has about 720 files and if I replace my local repository with the directory I can't install my project offline.
I also just can't copy the whole local repository because normally there are other artifacts in it that have nothing to do with my project.
Also I don't want to restart downloading everything over again (for example I could use -Dmaven.repo.local=directory but then it would start downloading artefacts that are already in my local repository).
Is there a way that I can use my local repository as a remote repository so mvn install/dependency:go-offline -Dmaven.repo.local=directory would copy the existing files from my local repository. Or is there way to get a list of all artifacts needed?

Comment: May I ask why you want to construct such a directory? If you just want to work offline, you can use (as you said) the go-offline goal and then work offline.

Comment: I need it in a seperate directory so i can filter through it and get all dependencies in the the form groupId:artifactId:version:packaging:classifier. Also i want to use this directory to upload all those artifacts to a nexus.

Comment: Why not upload all artifacts from the local repository to Nexus? You can scan first if they already exist and some extra artifacts probably won't do any harm.

Comment: I cant do that ... This would take way to much time and i only want to upload the artifacts from a specific project. So this is no option!

Comment: You _can_ reference one local repository as remote repository in the POM/settings.xml and copy artifacts to another local repository ... but I never tried that.. Just define a repository as usual and instead of a http address you put the local path.

Comment: How could i force maven to use the new profile instead of my profile with my remote repository?

Comment: The best way to handle repositories is to use the settings.xml. Then you can just exchange the settings.xml for another one.